# Why are my sortable headers giving me this error?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am building a component where I have 3 input fields that yield a datatable populated with the user's input on screen. In that datatable, the headers are to be sortable. In my console, I have no errors but when I attempt to click any of my headers to sort, I get this :

[image]

Anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my **Component**:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access = "global" >

        <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
    
        <aura:attribute name="GarageItems" type="List" default="[]"/>
        <aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List"/>
    
        <aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String" default="Name"/>
        <aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="string" default="asc" />
    
        <aura:attribute name="YearInput" type="Integer"/>
        <aura:attribute name="MakeInput" type="String"/>
        <aura:attribute name="ModelInput" type="String"/>

        <lightning:input aura:id="IdYear" name="CarYear" placeholder="Please type the Car's Year" value="{! v.YearInput }" />            
        <lightning:input aura:id="IdMake" name="CarMake" placeholder="Please type the Car's Make" value="{! v.MakeInput }" />        
        <lightning:input aura:id="IdModel" name="CarModel" placeholder="Please type the Car's Model" value="{! v.ModelInput }" />
    
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit action" onclick="{! c.SubmitData }" />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Clear Fields" title="Clear action" onclick="{! c.ClearFields }" />

    
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" horizontalAlign="center">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">
              <div style = "height: 300px">
                <lightning:datatable
                        keyField="id"
                        data="{!v.GarageItems}"
                        columns="{!v.Columns}"
                        hideCheckboxColumn="true"             
                        onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}"
                        sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"  
                        sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}">             
                </lightning:datatable>
            </div>  
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    

        

        
    
        

    


 </aura:component>
```

Here's my **Controller**:

```
({
    
    
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) 
        {
            try {
                cmp.set('v.Columns', 
                     [
                         {label: 'Year', fieldName: 'CarYear', sortable: 'true', type: 'integer'},
                         {label: 'Make', fieldName: 'CarMake', sortable: 'true', type: 'text'},
                         {label: 'Model', fieldName: 'CarModel',sortable: 'true', type: 'text'}
                     ]);
                }
            
            catch (ColumnsSet)
                {
                   console.log(ColumnsSet.message); 
                }
        },
    
    
    
    SubmitData : function(component, event, helper) 
        {                        
            try 
                {
                    let items = component.get("v.GarageItems");
                    
                    var Year = component.get("v.YearInput"); 
                    var Make = component.get("v.MakeInput"); 
                    var Model = component.get("v.ModelInput"); 
                    
                    if (Year && Make && Model) {
                        items.push({id: items.length+1, CarYear: Year, CarMake: Make, CarModel: Model });
                }
                
            component.set("v.GarageItems", items);}
            
            catch (ColumnsSet)
                {
                   console.log(ColumnsSet.message); 
                }
        },
    
    
    updateSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) 
        {
            var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
            var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
            
            cmp.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
            cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
            helper.sortData(cmp, fieldName, sortDirection);
        },
                           
                           
                           
     ClearFields : function(component, event, helper)
        {
            component.set("v.YearInput", "");
            component.set("v.MakeInput", "");
            component.set("v.ModelInput", "");
            
        }

                           
})
```

Here's my **Helper**:

```
({
    
    sortData: function (cmp, fieldName, sortDirection)
        {
            var fname = fieldName;
            var data = cmp.get("v.GarageItems");
            var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
            
            data.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse))
            cmp.set("v.GarageItems", data);
        },
    
    
    sortBy: function (field, reverse)
        {
            var key = function(x) {return x[field]};
            reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
            return function (a, b) 
                {
                    return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
                }

        }    
})
```

Comment: is the missing closing curly brace `}` at the end of your `sortBy: function (field, reverse)` a typo, or is it really missing in your code?

Comment: Oh my god. I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you. I'm gonna edit this into a new question because now I get errors when I click to sort the header. Thank you.

Comment: In the HTML file, you have `onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}"`, but in the JS file you have `updateSorting`. This could be causing the error.

Comment: That was it!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of having an answer...

There were 2 issues here.

First, was that the `sortBy: function (field, reverse)` helper function was missing a closing curly brace at the end

```js
sortBy: function (field, reverse)
        {
            var key = function(x) {return x[field]};
            reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
            return function (a, b) 
                {
                    return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
                }

        // This closing curly brace was missing
        // Missing braces cause a whole variety of strange errors
        //}
```

The second issue was that one of the functions being invoked in the aura component used a different name in the controller

Controller contained `updateSorting: function (cmp, event, helper){...}`
Component was calling `c.updateColumnSorting`

```html
<lightning:datatable
    keyField="id"
    data="{!v.GarageItems}"
    columns="{!v.Columns}"
    hideCheckboxColumn="true"             
    onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}" <!-- This here is the problem line -->
    sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"  
    sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}">             
</lightning:datatable>
```